# Django Pandas to http response (download file)

Tags: python, django, pandas

Python: 2.7.11

Django: 1.9

Pandas: 0.17.1

How should I go about creating a potentially large xlsx file download? I'm creating a xlsx file with pandas from a list of dictionaries and now need to give the user possibility to download it. The list is in a variable and is not allowed to be saved locally (on server).

Example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(self.csvdict)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

This example would just create the file and save it where the executing script is located. What I need is to create it to a http response so that the user would get a download prompt.

I have found a few posts about doing this for a xlsxwriter but non for pandas. I also think that I should be using 'StreamingHttpResponse' for this and not a 'HttpResponse'.

Comment: If the file is very large you might consider CSV instead of xlsx. I noticed that Pandas can be much faster working with CSV compared to working with Excel. At least on my computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jmcnamara is pointing you in the rigth direction. Translated to your question you are looking for the following code:

```
sio = StringIO()
PandasDataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(self.csvdict)
PandasWriter = pandas.ExcelWriter(sio, engine='xlsxwriter')
PandasDataFrame.to_excel(PandasWriter, sheet_name=sheetname)
PandasWriter.save()

sio.seek(0)
workbook = sio.getvalue()

response = StreamingHttpResponse(workbook, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
```

Notice the fact that you are saving the data to the StringIO variable and not to a file location. This way you prevent the file being saved before you generate the response.

Comment: How would this work in Python 3? I'm getting this error message: "string argument expected, got 'bytes'"

Comment: @Johan use BytesIO instead of StringIO.

Answer (score 16):

I will elaborate on what @jmcnamara wrote. This if for the latest versions of Excel, Pandas and Django. The import statements would be at the top of your views.py and the remaining code could be in a view:

```
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse
try:
    from io import BytesIO as IO # for modern python
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO as IO # for legacy python

# this is my output data a list of lists
output = some_function()
df_output = pd.DataFrame(output)

# my "Excel" file, which is an in-memory output file (buffer) 
# for the new workbook
excel_file = IO()

xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

df_output.to_excel(xlwriter, 'sheetname')

xlwriter.save()
xlwriter.close()

# important step, rewind the buffer or when it is read() you'll get nothing
# but an error message when you try to open your zero length file in Excel
excel_file.seek(0)

# set the mime type so that the browser knows what to do with the file
response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

# set the file name in the Content-Disposition header
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx'

return response
```

Comment: A small correction: For legacy python it must be: from io import StringIO as IO

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit off-topic, but it's worth pointing out that the `to_csv` method is generally faster than `to_excel`, since excel contains format information of the sheets. If you only have data and not formatting information, consider `to_csv`. Microsoft Excel can view and edit csv files with no problem.

One gain by using `to_csv` is that `to_csv` function can take any file-like object as the first argument, not only a filename string. Since Django response object is file-like, `to_csv` function can directly write to it. Some codes in your view function will look like:

```py
df = <your dataframe to be downloaded>
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=<default filename you wanted to give to the downloaded file>'
df.to_csv(response, index=False)
return response
```

Reference:

1. https://gist.github.com/jonperron/733c3ead188f72f0a8a6f39e3d89295d
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-csv/

Comment: hi ... is there a way to add context to this response?   for example in addition to the download, I would like to return {'number_of_records' : 10} to the html page

Answer (score 2):

With Pandas 0.17+ you can use a StringIO/BytesIO object as a filehandle to `pd.ExcelWriter`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()

# Use the StringIO object as the filehandle.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the data frame to the StringIO object.
pd.DataFrame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
xlsx_data = output.getvalue()

print len(xlsx_data)
```

After that follow the XlsxWriter Python 2/3 HTTP [examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_http_server.html).

For older versions of Pandas you can use this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058563/write-to-stringio-object-using-pandas-excelwriter/28065603#28065603).

Comment: Your example works fine. I'm getting an empty xlsx file with this. My question right now is how could I use this but with my list of dictionaries? In my example is the 'self.csvdict' the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share a class-based view approach to this, using elements from the answers above. Just override the `get` method of a Django `View`. My model has a JSON field which contains the results of dumping a dataframe to JSON with the `to_json` method.

Python version is 3.6 with Django 1.11.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class myModel(models.Model):
    json_field = JSONField(verbose_name="JSON data")

# views.py
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO as IO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

from .models import myModel

class ExcelFileDownloadView(View):
    """
    Allows the user to download records in an Excel file
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        obj = myModel.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        excel_file = IO()
        xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
        pd.read_json(obj.json_field).to_excel(xlwriter, "Summary")
        xlwriter.save()
        xlwriter.close()

        excel_file.seek(0)

        response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(),
                                content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="excel_file.xlsx"'
        return response

# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ExcelFileDownloadView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mymodel/(?P<pk>\d+)/download/$', ExcelFileDownloadView.as_view(), name="excel-download"),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two requirements that should be separate:

1. Creating a .xlsx file using python or pandas--it looks like you're good on this part.
2. Serving a downloadable file (django); see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062987/serving-excelxlsx-file-to-the-user-for-download-in-djangopython) or [maybe this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993645/django-to-serve-generated-excel-file)

Comment: Thanks for the posts. I already found the first one but it did not seem to work for me. The second one makes the concept a bit clearer but still no use. If I try to combine the xlsx creation and http response the only thing that happens is that a new xlsx gets created in the root of my project. I don't get any download prompt.