# csv download doesn't occur without error in Django

Tags: django, pandas, bytesio

I am implementing csv donwloand function referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267585/django-pandas-to-http-response-download-file).
Even though I don't get any error message, cannot get csv file downloaded.
Does anyone know what is the problem for this implementation?
Below is the code to download csv file from database.

```
class timeCSVexport(View):

    def get(self,request,pk,keyword):

        key=keyword.replace("_"," ")
        queryset=timeseries.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=key)

        bio = BytesIO()
        data=json.loads(list(queryset)[0].df)
        df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index').T
        df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
        df1=df.sort_index()

        sheet=key[:31] if len(key)>31 else key
        print (sheet)
        writer=pd.ExcelWriter(bio,engine='xlsxwriter')
        df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet)
        writer.save()

        bio.seek(0)
        workbook=bio.getvalue()

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(workbook,content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % pk

        return response
```

Comment: You should use request.FILES to get your file upload then use pandas.read_csv to read the csv into a df.

Comment: I already have data stored in database and want to download that file as csv file. I confirmed that data extraction from database and converting data structure to dataframe worked fine.

Comment: I apologies I miss understood your question. Are you getting any errors? Also is it writing a blank file?