# Excel file downloaded through Django's StreamingHttpResponse shows 'invalid format' on opening

Tags: python, django, pandas, xlsx

Django 2.2.5 | Python 3.6.12

I'm trying to create an xlsx file for download using a list of dictionaries through pandas. Since the file can become huge, I'm using StreamingHttpResponse() instead of normal HttpResponse(). The code that I have currently downloads the file but shows **file format is invalid** when I try and open it. I have referred to these two links as of now:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files

[Django Pandas to http response (download file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267585/django-pandas-to-http-response-download-file)

Here's the code that I am using currently:

```py
# 'emails' is the list of dictionaries
# 'list_name' contains the name of file

with BytesIO() as bio:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(bio, engine='xlsxwriter')
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=emails)
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Verify Results")
    writer.save()

    bio.seek(0)
    workbook = bio.getvalue()

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
                workbook,
                content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f"attachment; filename={list_name}.xlsx"

    return response
```

However, if I use

```py
response = HttpResponse(
    bio,
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
)
```

it downloads and opens up correctly.

How do I use StreamingHttpResponse with pandas so that it downloads correctly?

Comment: It probably isn't possible to "stream" a xlsx file since it is a zip file and it cannot be sent until the file is completely written. It isn't like a CSV file like in the link above.

Comment: @jmcnamara is right, but the technical reason why it throws error is that StreamingHttpResponse first argument is supposed to be iterator.